# How to extract chi-value and p-value from chisq.test(Matrix,correct=FALSE) in R

Tags: r, chi-squared

I am getting chisq.test(Matrix,correct=FALSE) result like this.

```
 X-squared = 38.224, df = 1, p-value = 6.306e-10
```

i am able to fetch p-value from this command. but how to fetch chi-value .

```
chisq.test(x)$p.value
```

Comment: Look at the help page `?chisq.test`, specifically the "Value" section.

Comment: `Xsq$statistic`

Comment: `str` is another very useful function to inspect object.  - try `str(Xsq)` to see its elements

Answer (score 4):

You'll find it easier if you assign the result of `chisq.test` to a variable.

```
Xsq <- chisq.test(x)
```

Now typing `names(Xsq)` will show you which properties of `Xsq` can be returned.

```
[1] "statistic" "parameter" "p.value"   "method"    "data.name" "observed"  
"expected"  "residuals"
[9] "stdres"
```

I assume `Xsq$statistic` is what you want.